# Отслеживание состояние таблицы в базе данных

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте. Как можно осуществить отслеживание новых записей в таблице базы данных. Есть `PHP` код который каждую минуту через `crontab` вытягивает данные из таблицы.

Допустим мы добавили 2 строки в эту таблицу. И при следующем обходе надо отследить добавления и вытянуть это эти самые 2 строки. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: пишите время добавления в поле таблицы и выбирайте по времени

Comment: Первая идея это использовать timestapm для записей. Где-то сохранять timestamp последнего обращения и читать записи у которых timestamp больше.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис вы имели ввиду у которых timestamp меньше?

Comment: timestamp всегда увеличивается. Чем новее запись тем он больше.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис хорошо. Если использовать timestamp то с какой строкой надо сравнивать его значение? Если добавиться больше чем 1 запись, допуститим 20.

Comment: 1. Создаёте новую таблицу. В ней одна колонка. Туда при обращении к данным записываете timestamp.(При чтении)

Comment: Создать поле `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0`. Выбираем соответственно по нулевому значению. Выбрав запись, пишем в поле время выборки записи. Либо наоборот - `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` а при выборке его обнулять.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно к каждой таблице приделать столбцы timestamp, но если таких таблиц сотни - это накладно

Можно сделать следующее:

1. Создать новую таблицу, в которой будет содержаться информация о количестве строк в нужных Вам таблицах. Например:

   [bd_info] {table_name, row_count}
2. Далее скрипт вычисляет количество записей в нужной таблице через:

   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME

   3. Сравниваете полученное количество строк из нужной таблицы с соответствующей записью в таблице [bd_info]
   4. Если количество записей различается, делаете выборку из TABLE_NAME с нужным лимитом, равным этому различию, при этом сортируете выборку по ID по убыванию

Примерный абстрактный код такой:

```
$count = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME";
$last_count = "SELECT row_count FROM bd_info WHERE table_name=TABLE_NAME";
$limit = $count - $last_count;
if ($limit > 0) {
    $new_rows = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
    "UPDATE bd_info SET(row_count = $count) WHERE table_name=TABLE_NAME";
}
```

В итоге в $new_rows будут содержаться последние добавленные записи.

Comment: Хотя лучше всего записывать в BD_INFO не количество строк в row_count а ID последней записи в таблицы и далее делать выборку по (table_name)ID > (bd_info) row_count - В таком случае можно избежать казусов из-за удаления записей

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но есть проблемка. Если на сайте будут несколько юзеров одновременно, то новые новости отобразятся только первому нажавшему кнопку "Показать новые новости". А остальные увидят новые только после перезагрузки страницы. Я не написал об этом в вопросе. Я подумал об этом уже после.

Comment: Речь же вроде шла про crontab, такой скрипт работает глобально и вряд ли подвязан к пользователю. В любом случае, можно сделать: а) расширить таблицу bd_info, добавив в нее столбец user_id и учитывать его. б) записывать данные из bd_info в сессию пользователя и делать выборку не из таблицы, а из сессии

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоватся триггером на `insert`. Отслеживаем добавление новых данных, когда в таблицу `events` будут добовлятся новые данные, тригер автоматом будет записывать новые ID и время добавления в таблицу `new_events`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `listen_insert_events` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `events` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO new_events Set id = NEW.id , datetime = NOW() + 0;
END
```

Теперь всегда можно отслеживать поступление новых событий в базу. 
Дальше, как ты уже написал выше, каждую минуту дергаеш из этой таблицы новые записи которые были добавлены, если нужны сугубо новые за минуту, то можно этим же джобом после выборки данных очищать таблицу `TRUNCATE new_events`, либо удалять последние n записей, предположим которые старше 1 часа, ну или вообще ничего не удалять а дергать из этой таблицы последние 5-10 записей.